# ADFS maintenance to SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, adfs

I need to schedule a three hour of maintenance of our SQL Server cluster that contains also the ADFS database (AdfsConfiguration and AdfsArtifactStore) and during this period the databases will be unreachable.

During the maintenance the ADFS services (login, issuance of claim tokens, etc) will it continue to work with the configuration already loaded from the database or the ADFS services will stop working during the "unavailability" of the cluster?
Thanks for tour help

Comment: If you have a SQL server cluster then this won't be an issue, the whole point of a cluster is that you can take a *single node* offline and fail over to a secondary while you perform routine maintenance such as patching.

Comment: unfortunately it's not that simple...maintenance concerns physical devices that involve the whole server rack and foresee the unavailability of the whole cluster.

Comment: Then I would suggest your *cluster* is insufficient to meet your business needs, clustering  sql servers should have zero shared points of failure, except for a Windows cluster with shared storage; availability groups should be on physically separate nodes with dedicated storage or multipath IO storage with a failover replica ideally off-site.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but I'm not a DBA and I'm not responsible for the SQL infrastructure.. I just use it.

I have received notice from the IT department that this maintenance is needed and I’m trying to figure out how to deal with the ADFS servers.

I need to understand if I can continue to provide ADFS services even without a connection to the DB or if I have to organize myself to transfer data and connections to a temporary SQL instance to be used during cluster maintenance in order to allow to the users of my organization to continue to log-in.